# Override function value with asynchronous call

Tags: asynchronous, emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

How can I use `cl-letf` or similar to override a symbol's function value during an async call?  I want to stop a buffer being displayed after calls to `start-process` or `start-process-shell-command`, and instead get back a string instead.

Here is a simplified example where binding `display-buffer` works for the synchronous version but not the async version.  Also, I have set lexical-binding to true.

```
(defun tst-fun-sync (url)
  (call-process "wget" nil "*wget*" nil url "-O" "-")
  (with-current-buffer "*wget*"
    (display-buffer (current-buffer))))

(defun tst-fun-async (url)
  (set-process-sentinel
   (start-process "wget" "*wget*" "wget" url "-O" "-")
   #'(lambda (p _m)
       (when (zerop (process-exit-status p))
         (with-current-buffer (process-buffer p)
           (display-buffer (current-buffer)))))))

(defun tst-fun-no-display (fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'display-buffer)
             #'(lambda (&rest _ignored)
                 (message "%s" (buffer-string)))))
    (apply fun args)))

;; The first has desired result, but not the second
;; (tst-fun-no-display 'tst-fun-sync "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
;; (tst-fun-no-display 'tst-fun-async "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: How about using `shell-command-to-string`?  E.g., `(replace-regexp-in-string "\n" "" (shell-command-to-string "date"))`  There is no need to display a buffer to work with it -- i.e., there is no need to use `display-buffer` in your example that I can see.

Comment: You may also be interested in a process filter that can capture all of the process output in the form of strings.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define a macro which temporarily rebinds `set-process-sentinel` so that the sentinel function can be decorated with a wrapper function.

```
(defmacro with-sentinel-wrapper (wrapper-fn &rest body)
  (let ((sps (gensym))
        (proc (gensym))
        (fn (gensym)))
    `(let ((,sps (symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel)))
       (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'set-process-sentinel)
                  (lambda (,proc ,fn)
                    (funcall ,sps ,proc (funcall ,wrapper-fn ,fn)))))
                ,@body))))
```

The wrapper can change the dynamic context in which the sentinel is called, by establishing any useful dynamic bindings. Here, I reuse your `cl-letf` to change what display does:

```
(with-sentinel-wrapper (lambda (fn)
                        (lexical-let ((fun fn)) 
                          (lambda (p m)
                            (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'display-buffer)
                                       #'(lambda (&rest _ignored)
                                           (message "%s" (buffer-string)))))
                              (funcall fun p m)))))
  (tst-fun-async "http://www.stackoverflow.com"))
```

Now, if you aren't sure that the asynchronous process actually calls `set-process-sentinel`, you may have to hack other functions.

Comment: thanks, but this seems to have the same result as my attempt - having no effect on the async version.  I think it wont work since unwind-protect does the bodyforms before async call finishes

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Thanks, I understand now. I changed my answer. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: awesome thanks!  So I guess the lexical environment gets tossed out somewhere in a regular set-process-sentinel call?  I wish I understood that better.  I had tried originally hacking the sentinel, but couldn't get that to work.  Luckily the functions Im targeting do use set-process-sentinel so ths is perfect

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Thanks. `cl-letf`, and most bindings in emacs unless otherwise specified, are dynamic: they come and go like the call-stack. So when you exit the function that calls the process creation, any binding in effect is gone. Later, when the sentinel is called, the code is run with the global bindings. What I am doing here is to ensure that at the time the sentinel is called, our custom sentinel `(lambda (p m) ...)` changes the dynamic context in which the actual sentinel `fun` is called (note that I am using lexical-let here to store the actual sentinel function for future uses).

Comment: right, I am aware of elisp defaulting to dynamic scoping and am using `;; -*- lexical-binding: t-*-` at the top of my script, so using `let` in place of `lexical-let` works as well.  I had thought the closure would wrap the sentinel - I wonder if using `process-put` to attach a function to the process would be another option.  Thanks again, very helpful :)